# Show UUID and mac address using evothings ibeacon scan

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

i am new here and i am developing a project using cordova. In the example from evothings, there are ibeacon scan and Ble scan, in the ibeacon scan i can show the uuid, in the ble scan i can show the mac address. My question is if i can show the uuid and the mac address in the same project, is if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS different native libraries are used when scanning for iBeacon beacons vs when scanning for BLE devices in general.

At the lowest level, a BLE scan is performed when scanning for iBeacon devices, but on iOS, scanning for beacons is wrapped in Apple's CoreLocation library. For BLE scannning CoreBluetooth is used.

Problem is that CoreBluetooth hides certain BLE scan properties (you cannot get the MAC address on iOS), and also hides the iBeacon scan record, and CoreLocation only exposes iBeacon properties.

On Android, it is possible to get both iBeacon properties and BLE properties like the MAC address, but not on iOS.

Regards, Mikael